# What 1980s TV series has two men running from something and filling a pool with liquid in its opening credits?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for the name of an American TV series, broadcast in Italy in 1980s.

I was a child and I remember only a very small part of the opening credits: there are two men, probably dressed in blue. They're probably running away from something or someone. They open a valve and a liquid (water?) comes out from a pipeline (and fills something like a pool).

The scene looks like an industrial environment.

Comment: Do you mean TV series?

Comment: Yes, it's a TV series, broadcasted here in Italy in late 80's.

Comment: What makes you think this is science fiction?

Comment: Really, I don't remember very well... but I'm pretty sure the two men in the opening are running away from some sort of humanoids aliens

Comment: By "the opening", are you referring to an opening scene or the opening credits?

Comment: Opening credits.

Comment: In Italian, or dubbed or subtitled from another language?

Comment: Coming from USA, dubbed in Italian

Comment: Any more details on the costumes? Any logos? Common themes?

Comment: Really, I remember only few fragments... I remember the running man was white dressed, a white bodysuit

Comment: I can't watch the attached videos now since I'm at work, but this site contains quite a number of TV shows that were broadcast in Italy in the '80s: http://www.lifeinitaly.com/tv/italian-television-80

Answer (score 5):

If it could have been as late as 1990 or '91, it's possible that what you saw was not a fiction series but actually the game-show Fort Boyard [Fort Boyard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Boyard_(TV_series)) or the british variation thereof. A youtube video of [the intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-VOSZ9qXGc&feature=player_detailpage#t=115) from an unspecified season, shows the following scene at 1:59

[image: Pumps and pipes]

Here, two contestants clad in tight blue clothes, their team colour, is operating a pump and a pipe. There is also a lot of running and a sequence with an "hourglass" being filled with liquid, which might be a separte "pool-like" image. Finally, the location of the show is the real world offshore Fort Boyard, which together with the gameshow props might give the impression of an oceanic research facility.

[image: Hourglass]

Hourglass resembling a pool

[image: Real fort boyard]

The real-world fort boyard, location for the game-show.

The show first aired in France in 1990. I have not found information on when it aired in Italy, but an italian pilot episode was produced in 1991, indicating that it may already have had some success in italy in the preceding year. There are however many regional variations of this show, such as the british "The Crystal Maze" which also aired in 1990 but was not filmed on location at Fort Boyard. The Crystal Maze had four "zones" one of which was an industrial chemical plant [[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Maze#The_maze)] The following picture shows the contestants of the crystal maze enter the chemical plant in the first season:
[image]

However, nothing resembling the pumps and pipes task seemed to appear in this episode.

Counting against you having recalled Fort Boyard, is the year 1990. Also that the topmost picture in this answer may not be from the first-season opening credits, which would shift your recalled tv-show intro even further, to the mid 90s. As [this video of a first season episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CA1nSDlU8Cw) demonstrates, the opening back then consisted only of the contestants arriving via boat, though the task props throughout the episode include both chemistry equipment and pools of water.

Comment: Really a good answer. Unfortunately it's not the one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *Man From Atlantis*?  The [opening credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r94CDD6E8fI) don't match that description, but it is a later 70's TV show where there are a lot of people running around in blue skinsuits which takes place at an oceanic research facility, so plenty industrial and has lots of pools.

Also, the [Wikipedia entry notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_from_Atlantis):

> In Italy, the series is notable to be one of the early successes of the then interregional network Telemilano, future Canale 5, that began to air the series on February 11th, 1980 under the name L'Uomo di Atlantide.

Comment: Yes I remember it but is not the one I'm searching for. Thanks anyway!